# Change styling for specific jQuery UI object (selectmenu) and not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have two selectmenus. I want to change the look and feel of one of them. This is what I tried so far: Add two  selects then within the style tag, i tried to change the class `ui-selectmenu-button` and `ui-selectmenu-text` for only `select1` but no luck.

```
// JS
<script>
$("#select1").selectmenu();
$("#select2").selectmenu();
</script>

 // HTML
<select id="select1">     
<option value="1"> 1 </option>
</select>
<select id="select2">   
<option value="2"> 2 </option>  
</select>

// CSS
<style>   
#select1 .ui-selectmenu-button{     
    background: rgb(12,27,37);   
}   

#select1 .ui-selectmenu-text{   
   color: white;   
} 
</style>
```

If i simply do the thing below, it will work but change all the jquery ui selectmenus and i only want it to work for select1 in this example.

```
<style>
.ui-selectmenu-button{  
    background: rgb(12,27,37);   
}  
</style>
```

Comment: why your JS section placed before html DOM?

Comment: No specific reason, that shouldn't matter however?

Comment: Please change the selectors to: #select1.ui-selectmenu-button, without space between them, if the class and the id are related to one element.

Comment: @NadezhdaSerafimova jquery UI will not add a class to the `<select>`. It will hide the select and add it's generated HTML after it. Therefore the adjacent connector should be used. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target it using the Adjacent sibling connector.

```
#select1+.ui-selectmenu-button{  
   background: rgb(12,27,37);     
}
```

Since the #select1 element will be hidden, but still be preceding the code generated by jQuery UI, you can target it with the '+' sign in CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/vadt8neh/

Comment: bonus question in case you know, how to style the drop down when the select button is pressed. any ideas? my initial thought was `#select1+.ui-selectmenu-menu{  
   background: rgb(12,27,37);     
}  ` but that didn't work

Comment: bonus answer:
Turns out that the select-menu's have an ID that can be related to the ID of the original element. Try this: 
`#select1-menu{ 
  border: 3px solid blue; 
}

#select1-menu li{ 
  background: green; 
}
`
https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/vadt8neh/1/